# 16.04 ubuntu single sign on 'wrong e-mail or password'

Tags: 16.04, software-center, ubuntu-one, snap

Apparantly, one needs an Ubuntu SSO account for installing Snaps in 16.04 through ubuntu software (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773609/why-does-ubuntu-require-us-to-register-an-account-on-ubuntu-website-to-be-able-t) link). That's fine with me, but it keeps telling me that my username or password is wrong although I've just changed my password (in fact, twice just to be sure).

So, what could I do to prevent Ubuntu software to tell me my password is wrong, please?

Answer (score 7):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1616943) caused by the newest version of snapd.

You can work around the problem by opening a terminal and logging in with `sudo snap login` instead.

Comment: This command (+ my UO email address at the end) works to login, but i still cannot install snaps from GUI or is it only possible through CLI?

Comment: It is certainly possible to install snaps via GUI. You would need to be more specific about what problem you are encountering after the work around.

Comment: Ok sry, here is what I've done:
terminal: 
sudo snap login xxx@gmail.com
Password: 
Login successful
Then i go to ubuntu software but when i try to install a snap i get the dialog again for my Ubuntu One credentials which fails once again to login.

Answer (score 5):

Use terminal instead:

`~$ sudo snap install vlc
vlc (stable) daily from 'videolan' installed`