# "To install and remove snaps, you need an Ubuntu Single Sign-On account"

Tags: xubuntu

I recently bought two identical laptops and installed Xubuntu 16.04 on both of them.  Mostly for curiosity's sake, I choose different servers from which to "net install".  During the installation, I also chose some media packages on one of the laptops.

So, one computer installs software from the Software & Updates section normally, as I've been doing for year.

The other computer.  The one on which I installed media packages does not.  I get a login UI and the message: "To install and remove snaps, you need an Ubuntu Single Sign-On account".

Is there an easy way to get rid of this?

Comment: See [Why does Ubuntu require us to register an account on Ubuntu website to be able to install a Snap package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773609/why-does-ubuntu-require-us-to-register-an-account-on-ubuntu-website-to-be-able-t).

Comment: Thanks, Jonas.  That answers what it is.  But it's on one of my Xubuntu installations, and not the other.  I did two installations on two identical laptops and then attempted to install Brave Browser.  

One installed.  The other gave me this nonsense about snaps.

Comment: FYI: I ended up reinstalling.  It worked.  I was able to install the Brave Browser from the Software section without getting any message about snaps or single sign-on.